# Finding all the required PINS

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

If a PIN number consists of 6 characters and each of these characters could be one of the 26 alphabets or a number from 1 to 9, then how many different PINS are there where:

a) all five characters are the same and one character is different.

b) four characters are the same and two characters are same but different from the other four.

c) four characters are the same and two are different(i.e different from the other four and different from each other).

d) How many PINs are reverse of another PIN.(i.e reverse of ABCD12 is 21DCBA).

Can anyone explain how to approach these questions? I'm new to the topic.

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  Please edit your question to show what you have attempted and explain where you are stuck so that you receive responses that address the specific difficulties you are encountering.  This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: Yes I have edited.

Comment: In part (a), I assume you meant to write that five of the characters are the same and one character is different.  Here is a strategy for that part:  Choose which character will appear five times, choose which five positions it occupies, then choose which of the remaining characters (which must be different than the one that fills five positions) fills the remaining open position.